# IBM Worklight - Dojo Video widget doesn't work in iOS device

Tags: ios, video, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing a hybrid application for iOS using Dojo 1.9.1 as a JavaScript framework.

I'd like to play a video inside my app. The video is displayed into the dojo view (stopped) but I cannot play it.
I have also tried using HTML5 video tag... but still not working.

This is my code:

```
<video data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Video" controls>
  <source src="images/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: In which environment its not working in browser or the simulator?

Comment: It is not working in the device...

Comment: Which device are you playing?

Comment: Does the dojox/mobile/tests/test_Video.html give the same result ?

Comment: Yes, same problem... It plays the video before dojo libraries are loaded completly, then it shows a play button on the video but there's no way to play it...

Comment: @MariaBorbones, is the below answer of help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the following in Worklight 6.1.0 with an iPad running iOS 7.0.x:

1. Created a new Worklight project and application and chose [to add the Dojo Library via the wizard](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_03_Working_with_UI_frameworks.pdf)
2. Added the iPad environment
3. Added a video folder next to the JS and CSS folders in `common`, and placed in it a .mp4 file
4. Used the following in index.html: http://pastebin.com/dJPJGRU2
5. In `common\main.js` I've added `dojox/mobile/Video` to the `dojoInit()` function's `require`
6. Unchecked the "Provide Library Resources" option in the Dojo console in Eclipse

Running in both iOS Simulator and device, I could tap the play button to play the video.